# How to check if recipe has been included using include_recipe?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I read about [Chef wrapper cookbook](http://www.getchef.com/blog/2013/12/03/doing-wrapper-cookbooks-right/) and now I'm try to refactor some kitchen roles in role cookbooks. So for instance I have a lamp role cookbook which does something like this:

```
# This is coming from another cookbook
include_recipe 'mysql_role::default'
# Install and tune apache2
include_recipe 'lamp_role::apache2'
# Install php and usual modules
include_recipe 'lamp_role::php'
include_recipe 'lamp_role::php_modules'
```

Included recipes may have some application logic but they usually end with inclusion of official cookbooks

```
# in lamp_role::php recipe
include_recipe 'php'
```

Now in another recipe I'd like to check if the official `php::default` recipe has been included somewhere, I used to do that with one of these two syntaxes:

```
# This is true for recipes included both in roles and in run_list
include_recipe 'newrelic::php_agent' if node.recipes.include?('php')
# This works only for runlist recipes
include_recipe 'newrelic::php_agent' if node.recipe?('php')
```

Is there any way to check if a recipe has been included with `include_recipe` somewhere else?

P.S. I'm using chef-solo to deploy.

### Use case

I wrote a monitoring recipe which installs monit and add some templates, here's a fragment of code

```
# Install and configure monit
include_recipe 'monit'
# Template shouldn't be installed if apache is not present
monitrc 'apache2' do
  template_cookbook 'monitoring_role'
  # My previous attempt, which doesn't work if recipe is included with include_recipe
  only_if { node.recipes.include?('apache2') || node[:monit][:templates].include?('apache2') }
end
```

I've added an attribute (`node[:monit][:templates]`) to manually specify monit templates in node attributes, but it's pretty easy to forget them. Obviously I don't want the `apache2` recipe included in all hosts but I'm using this recipe in multiple machines and with the check I'm asking for I can reuse the recipe on all hosts and monit will be installed with templates for daemons present in the current node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can inspect the `run_context`. This is how [ChefSpec](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec) does it:

```rb
#
# Automatically appends "+::default+" to recipes that need them.
#
# @param [String] name
#
# @return [String]
#
def with_default(name)
  name.include?('::') ? name : "#{name}::default"
end

#
# The list of loaded recipes on the Chef run (normalized)
#
# @return [Array<String>]
#
def loaded_recipes
  @runner.run_context.loaded_recipes.map { |name| with_default(name) }
end
```

So that answers your question. Now my question - **why?**

Chef will automatically build up the dependency graph for you. It will only include the recipe once, at the appropriate place of order. You don't need to manually manage this graph, and it is "okay" to include the same recipe more than once.

In fact, internally, we use this pattern quite frequently. Each recipe declares the recipes it depends on at the very top. I'd recommend watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYt0E84kYUI

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm going to try it. I've added my use case to the original question, just to clarify why I need this.

Comment: And, of course, thanks for chefspec gem it speedup cookbooks development a lot.

Answer (score 1):

### Final toughts

[sethvargo answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22867032/518204) is correct, I can add a ruby file in the library folder of my cookbook with the following code to get the method I'm asking for

```
class Chef

  class Node
    def has_recipe?(recipe_name)
      loaded_recipes.include?(with_default(recipe_name))
    end

    private
    #
    # Automatically appends "+::default+" to recipes that need them.
    #
    # @param [String] name
    #
    # @return [String]
    #
    def with_default(name)
      name.include?('::') ? name : "#{name}::default"
    end

    #
    # The list of loaded recipes on the Chef run (normalized)
    #
    # @return [Array<String>]
    #
    def loaded_recipes
      node.run_context.loaded_recipes.map { |name| with_default(name) }
    end

  end

end
```

The example in my use case above is broken since `monitrc` is a definition and thus doesn't accept `only_if/not_if` blocks. So I need to rewrite that piece of code using plain ruby which is evaluated at **recipe compile time** [(see this)](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_nodes_chef_run.html). This is the modified code

```
if node.has_recipe?('apache2') # This if is evaluated when recipes are loaded
  monitrc 'apache2' do
    template_cookbook 'monitoring_role'  
  end
end
```

The important thing is that this code can have an inconsistent behavior. It depends on when the checked recipe is included. If I call this recipe `monitoring::default` and I have a recipe named `lamp::default` which calls `include_recipe 'apache2'`, in the following case the template is installed

```
run_list = ['lamp::default', 'monitoring::default']
```

while with this run list the call is evaluated to false

```
run_list = ['monitoring::default', 'lamp::default']
```

The `has_recipe?` method works fine with execute time guards, i.e.

```
package('foo') do
  only_if { node.has_recipe?('bar') }
end
```

works in every case.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a `recipe?` available method in [chef node](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/12.0.3/lib/chef/node.rb#L236), to check if a recipe is included in node run_list